# Why static_cast<Type>(object) copies object to Type?

Tags: c++

I am learning `static_cast<Type>(object)` in C++. I found it calls copy constructor of `Type` with `object`. Is is true? If it is true, why it copies it? I thought it just change how to use the memory pointed by object. If it needs constructing copy, `static_cast` has more cost than I thought. Do I need to care of the cost?

The followings are the test code,

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    Base(const Base& org) {
        std::cout << "Base Copy Constructor" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void static_casting(void) {
        static_cast<Base>(*this);
    }
};

void test_static_cast_copy_constructor(void) {
    Derived a;
    a.static_casting();
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, [you're **slicing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) the object with that cast.

Comment: If you want to change how the memory is used, use `static_cast<Type&>`. All remarks about slicing still apply.

Comment: "I thought it just change how to use the memory pointed by object." You thought wrong. In fact, in most cases `static_cast<Type>(object)` is *defined* as doing `Type value(object)` for some imaginary object `value`.That want it does by definition. That's what `static_cast` is for.

Comment: You are asking whether the copy constructor is used, why don't you put some output into it and try it yourself? Still, casting to an object type will create a new object.

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig. I did not know static_cast can slice the object.

Comment: Thank you Raymond Chen for letting me know how to avoid constructing copy.

Comment: Thank you AnT for telling what is static_cast deeply. Please let me ask a little bit more. Is static_cast is same as casting in C language?

Comment: Thank you Ulrich Eckhardt for commenting. I supposed I ask Why ~ not Whether ~. My English might not be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting `static_cast` to work like it does with pointers, but there is no pointer casting happening in your code. `static_cast<Type *>(&object)` would yield a pointer to `Type`, and dereferencing it would indeed let you treat `object` as though it were of type `Type` (I assume this is what you mean when you say "change how to use the memory pointed by object"). This is possible because `object` still exists in its original form somewhere in the memory, and the pointer in effect only provides access to a portion of `object`'s data and behaviour.

However, as pointed out in the comments, `static_cast<Type>(object)` yields a new object of type `Type` - and since a new object is created, the appropriate constructor is called, with the portions of the copied object not contained in a`Type` object chucked out (sliced).

Comment: Thank you for jaymmer. You are right. I expected all static_cast use object as a pointer. Thanks to you and guys above, I understand what is static_cast. And what I wanted is static_cast<Type&>(object). Thank you again.